# Нужна ли запятая перед "ну и"?

Tags: запятые

*Я с утра помылся, побрился ну и поел [, конечно же].*

Comment: Что-то там, ближе к концу, странное. Объясните?

Comment: Что странное: "ну и" или "конечно же"? "Конечно же" поставил в скобки (можно с ним, а можно без него), а запятая с пробелом, как должно быть, если включить КЖ.

Comment: Но ведь после обычной скобки запятая не ставится.

Comment: А после такой ставится? Я понимаю, что то, что мне надо было выразить, выходит за рамки обычного употребления.

Comment: Потому и скобки непростые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Я с утра помылся, побрился, ну и поел, конечно же.***

Грамота называет ***НУ И*** присоединительным союзом, и с этим можно согласиться, так как его можно заменить союзом ***А ТАКЖЕ***. Поэтому запятая перед НУ И **ставится.**

Из словаря:

[https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/474/ну_и](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/474/%D0%BD%D1%83_%D0%B8)

Вопрос № 298998
Следует ли обособлять слово "конечно же" в предложении "Ну и конечно же желаю, чтобы деньги текли к вам рекой, любви было море, а счастья — океан!"

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
 ***Ну и, конечно же, желаю...***

```
Вопрос № 296426
```

Здравствуйте! Ставится ли запятая в предложении, начинающемся на: "Ну и(,) в-третьих, ..."?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Вводное слово обычно не отделяется знаком препинания **от присоединительного союза,** стоящего в начале предложения. Таким образом, запятая после И не требуется.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! 